# Java applet methods

Tags: java, swing, applet

This is my program:

```
import java.applet.*; // imports basic applet package
import java.awt.*; // imports the abstract windows toolkit
import java.awt.event.*; // imports the events package from the abstract windows toolking
import java.util.Random; // imports package for randomizing numbers

public class Game extends Applet implements KeyListener
{

    public int x = 240; // sets the x variable
    public int y = 230; // sets the y variable
    private Image dbImage; // Variable for doublebuffering
    private Graphics dbg; // Variable for doublebuffering
    Image startscreen; // declares startscreen as an image
    Image instructions; // declares insturctions as an image
    Image background; // declares background as an image
    Random rand = new Random (); // declares the random variable


    public void init ()
    {
        Game b = new Game ();
        addKeyListener (this);
        setSize (500, 500); // sets the size of the screen
        //setBackground (Color.WHITE); // sets the backround color
        startscreen = getImage (getDocumentBase (), "startscreen.png"); // gets the "startscreen.png" image
        for (int p = 0 ; p < 1000 ; p++)
        {
        }
        instructions = getImage (getDocumentBase (), "instructions.png"); // gets the "instructions.png" image
        for (int o = 0 ; o < 1000 ; o++)
        {
        }
        background = getImage (getDocumentBase (), "background.png"); // gets the "background.png" image
        Game.bombs ();
    }


    public void backgrounds (Graphics g)
    {
        setSize (500, 500);
        g.drawImage (startscreen, 0, 0, this); // draws the startscreen
        g.drawImage (instructions, 0, 0, this); // draws the instructions
        g.drawImage (background, 0, 0, this); // draws the background
    }


    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawImage (startscreen, 0, 0, this); // draws the startscreen
        repaint ();
        g.drawImage (instructions, 0, 0, this); // draws the instructions
        repaint ();
        g.drawImage (background, 0, 0, this);
        g.setColor (Color.GRAY); // sets the body of the tank to GRAY
        g.fillRect (x, y, 30, 50); // body of tank
        g.setColor (Color.BLACK); // sets the rest of the tank to BLACK
        g.fillRect (x - 10, y - 10, 10, 70); // left wheel of tank
        g.fillRect (x + 30, y - 10, 10, 70); // right wheel of tank
        g.fillRect (x + 5, y + 20, 20, 20); // top of tank
        g.fillRect (x + 10, y - 20, 10, 50); // barrel of tank
    }


    public void keyTyped (KeyEvent e)
    {
    }


    public void update (Graphics g)
    {

        // initialize buffer
        if (dbImage == null)
        {
            dbImage = createImage (this.getSize ().width, this.getSize ().height); // sets the width, height, etc of doublebuffer
            dbg = dbImage.getGraphics (); // gets the image
        }

        // clear screen in background
        dbg.setColor (getBackground ()); // gets the background for the double buffer
        dbg.fillRect (0, 0, this.getSize ().width, this.getSize ().height); // gets teh size of the width, height, etc of background

        // draw elements in background
        dbg.setColor (getForeground ()); // sets the forground for the doulbebuffer
        paint (dbg); // draws the image for the double buffer

        g.drawImage (dbImage, 0, 0, this); // draw image on the screen

    }


    public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e)
    {

        if (e.getKeyCode () == 37) // checks if left arrow is pressed
        {
            x -= 10; // moves the tank over 4 to the left
            repaint ();
        } // end if for left arrow
        if (e.getKeyCode () == 39) // checks if up arrow is pressed
        {
            x += 10; // moves the tank over 4 to the right
            repaint ();
        } // end if for up arrow
        if (e.getKeyCode () == 38) // checks if right arrow is pressed
        {
            y -= 10;
            repaint ();
        } // end if for right arrow
        if (e.getKeyCode () == 40) // checks if down arrow is pressed
        {
            y += 10;
            repaint ();
        } // end if for down arrow
        if (e.getKeyCode () == 32) // checks if space is pressed
        {
            repaint ();
        } // end if for space
        if (x > 460) // makes sure that the tank does not pass the right wall
        {
            x -= 10;
        }
        if (x < 10) // makes sure that the tank does not pass the left wall
        {
            x += 10;
        }
        if (y > 440) // makes sure that the tank does not pass the bottom wall
        {
            y -= 10;
        }
        if (y < 20) // makes sure that the tank does not pass the top wall
        {
            y += 10;
        }
    }


    public void keyReleased (KeyEvent e)
    {
    }


    public void bombs (Graphics g)
    {
        int pick = 0;
        int pick2 = 0;

        for (int j = 0 ; j < 1 ; j++) // for loop for counter
        {
            pick = rand.nextInt (500); // randomizes random integers from 0 to 500
            //System.out.println (pick); // prints the integers
        } // end for loop for randomize

        for (int m = 0 ; m < 1 ; m++) // for loop for randomize integer
        {
            pick2 = rand.nextInt (500); // randomizes intger from 0 to 500
        }
        g.fillRect (pick, pick2, 100, 100); // draws the bombs
        if (x < pick + 10 || x > pick + 10) // collision detection for x
        {
        }
        if (y < pick2 + 10 || y > pick2 + 10) // collision detection for y
        {
        }

    }
}
```

can you please tell me how to call in "bombs" in a different place?
i want to call bombs in inside KeyPressed

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do it: have your `paint()` method call `bombs()` if a boolean flag member variable is set. Then in your key listener, set the flag and call `repaint()`. The `paint()` method can clear the flag after calling the method. That way you can call it from anywhere; when `paint()` is called by `repaint()`, it will be able to supply the `Graphics` argument and call the method correctly.

So in `paint()` you might have

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    ...
    if (shouldShowBombs) {
        bombs(g);
        shouldShowBombs = false;
    }
```

Then if you want to paint the bombs anywhere in your applet, you just write

```
shouldShowBombs = true;
repaint();
```

Of course, you have to declare `shouldShowBombs`

```
public class Game {
    private boolean shouldShowBombs = false;
```

Comment: but how do i call "bombs" in to paint?

Comment: In the code you show above, `bombs(Graphics g)` takes a parameter of type `Graphics`; but the error messages you show indicate that you're removed that parameter from the method. I don't know why you've done this -- perhaps you were just fooling around. You need to put it back.